# Стандартные базы данных, можно ли удалить?

Tags: mysql

Установил на сервере LAMP, поставил phpmyadmin
Захожу, вижу 4 базы данных.
МОжно ли их удалять? Вижу что туст пуста и название говорит само за себя, ее удалю.
А остальные важны, нужны? что в них?[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно удалить только test, в остальных хранится служебная инфа.